# Mouse wheel not scrolling in JDialog but working in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jdialog

I'm facing a frustrating issue. I have an application where the scroll wheel doesn't work in a JDialog window (but works in a JFrame).

Here's the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Failtest extends JFrame {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
          new Failtest();             
       }
    });

 }

 public Failtest() {
  super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  setTitle("FRAME");
  JScrollPane sp1 = new   JScrollPane(getNewList());
  add(sp1);
  setSize(150, 150);
        setVisible(true);


  JDialog d = new JDialog(this, false);// NOT WORKING
        //JDialog d = new JDialog((JFrame)null, false); // NOT WORKING
        //JDialog d = new JDialog((JDialog)null, false);// WORKING - WHY? 

  d.setTitle("DIALOG");
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(getNewList());

  d.add(sp);
  d.setSize(150, 150);
  d.setVisible(true);
 }

 public JList getNewList() {
  String objs[] = new String[30];
  for(int i=0; i<objs.length; i++) {
  objs[i] = "Item "+i;
 }
 JList l = new JList(objs);
  return l;
 }
}
```

I found a solution which is present as a comment in the java code - the constructor receiving a (JDialog)null parameter.

Can someone enlighten me?
My opinion is that this is a java bug.

Tested on Windows XP-SP3 with 1 JDK and 2 JREs:

```
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_17

D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin>java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin>cd ..

D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17>java -version
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thank you in advance,

Iulian Şerbănoiu

PS: The problem is not new - the code is taken from a forum ([here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=723367)) where this problem was also mentioned - but no solutions to it (yet)

**LATER EDIT:**
The problem persists with jre/jdk_1.6.0_10, 1.6.0_16 also

**LATER EDIT 2:**
Back home, tested on linux (Ubuntu - lucid/lynx) - both with openjdk and sun-java from distribution repo and it works (I used the .class file compiled on Windows) !!! - so I believe I'm facing a JRE bug that happens on some Windows configurations.

Comment: Please, don't give us questions 2-in-1.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I only said this is not working with JDialog on some configurations (XP SP3 my case) and I'd like to know a workaround if possible. I know now that on some configurations (event with same JRE) it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something weird with your java install : your default version is not the 1.6.0_17 you show us, but an even more recent 1.6.0_18.

Anyway, using my (just a little older) 1.6.0_16 version on Windows XP, I cannot reproduce your issue, letting me think it may be a bug in J

Comment: Look at the command line. For development I use JDK 1.6.0_17(which contains also JRE with the same version) but the system (when I moved out of bin directory) has a newer JRE (1.6.0_18)

Comment: Yes, of course, but I personnally tend to develop using the JDK that the systelm uses as default, for the sake of coherence. Anyway, I was not able to reproduce your behaviour in my JDK 1.6.0_16, and THAT is weird.

Comment: Indeed - I'm downloading the JDK 1.6.0_16 and will check the results. Thanks for the hint

Comment: I edited the answer - the problem persists even with jdk 1.6.0_16

Comment: Are we talinkg about the same thing ? From testing it on my box, I believed it worked with my version, but you say it don't. So, here is my test : I took your code, compiled it, then run it. Two windows showed, one titled 'FRAME' and the other titled 'DIALOG'. On each of them, without clicking on it, when i scroll the wheel, nothing happens. But when I click the window title bar, and scroll, the list moves correctly. So, what is the defective behaviour ?

Comment: The scroll works in the Frame but doesn't work in the Dialog (only with the hack present in the code as comment). This is the *real* problem. I tested on linux - it works there ... so it's a problem with my Windows configuration (it is very possible that this is a JRE bug, triggered by some system configuration)

Answer (score 1):

Its not a bug, when using:

```
 JDialog d = new JDialog(this, false);
 JDialog d = new JDialog((JFrame)null, false);
```

You are calling the constructor with **`Frame`** in the first parameter

But when using

```
 JDialog d = new JDialog((JDialog)null, false);
```

You are calling the constructor with **`JDialog`** in the first parameter

Might be confusing because both are `null` but even though, you should specify which constructor exactly you want.

**UPDATE**
After your comment, i just realized whats the problem :), im unable to reproduce it though. The mouse scrolls in both the Dialog and the Frame. I'm using Java 1.6 on Snow Leopard

Comment: Then why the scroll works only in the "(JDialog)null" case? This is the real question. I actually need an explanation - this solution for me is *just* a hack

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to reproduce this on my system (Java 6u18 on Windows 7).  However, I suspect that this is a focus issue, where the mouse events aren't being received by the scrollpane when you use the `JFrame` version of the `JDialog` constructor and yet they are being received when you use the `JDialog` version.

Several things you can try here:

1. You can try clicking on the dialog and/or the dialog's scrollbar and see if mouse scrolling affects the scrollbar after you have clicked on it.
2. You can programmatically request focus for the scrollpane by calling [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29).
3. If `requestFocusInWindow()` fails, try [`requestFocus()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus%28%29).  (`requestFocus()` is discouraged because of platform-specific variations in its behavior, but you appear to have a platform-specific problem.)
4. You can add a [`FocusListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html) to your scrollpane to track when it gains and loses focus, which should help you confirm whether this problem has anything to do with focus at all.
5. You can add a [`MouseWheelListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelListener.html) to your scrollpane to see if each [`MouseWheelEvent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseWheelEvent.html) is being received by the scrollpane or not.

Like I said, I couldn't reproduce this problem on my system, but these are the things I would try if I were troubleshooting a problem like the one you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not likely the answer, but can you please entertain us and FIX your buggy code such that the frame is created on the EDT (as per Sun's specifications)??

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Failtest();             
        }
    });
}
```

Until you've done, I'm not sure you can rule out anything.

I've got a "works for me" using Windows Vista on JRE 1.6.0_20.

Comment: You are right - it's not the answer, but I did modify the code according to your suggestion. +1 for that. Thanks